# WPF Databinding, value won't update

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I know this is terribly common issue, but I just can't get the button to update to "Pressed1" and "Pressed2" content when changing "Default" of buttonContent. Having looked at few questions, I can't find the answer that'd work for me, I simply can't find out what is wrong here, so here's the crappy code:

The window with a button

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Code_Behind cB;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        cB = new Code_Behind();
        this.DataContext = cB;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cB.buttonPressed();
    }
}
```

And here's the separate class

```
   public class Code_Behind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _buttonContent = "Default";
    public string buttonContent
    {
        get { return _buttonContent; }
        set { 
                if (_buttonContent != value) 
                    {
                        buttonContent = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("buttonContent"); 
                    } 
            }
    }
    public void buttonPressed()
    {
        int timesPressed = 0;
        if (timesPressed != 1)
        {
                _buttonContent = "Pressed1";
                timesPressed++;
        }
        else if (timesPressed != 2)
        {
                _buttonContent = "Pressed2";
                timesPressed++;
                timesPressed = 0;
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the property, but the backing field. Hence the `PropertyChanged` event is not fired.

Replace

```
_buttonContent = "Pressed1";
...
_buttonContent = "Pressed2";
```

with

```
buttonContent = "Pressed1";
...
buttonContent = "Pressed2";
```

---

Besides that, it is a widely accepted convention to write property names with Pascal casing, i.e. `ButtonContent` instead of `buttonContent`.

Moreover, your property setter looks odd (probably because you try to squeeze too much code in one line).

Instead of

```
set
{
    if (_buttonContent != value)
    {
        _buttonContent = value;
    } 
    OnPropertyChanged("buttonContent");
}
```

it should certainly be

```
set
{
    if (_buttonContent != value)
    {
        _buttonContent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("buttonContent");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's actually the problem here it seems. Well, it never explained how exactly properties worked in the first place. Is there a difference between binding to an object instance of the class or directly to the class though?

Comment: Binding "directly to the class" would mean binding to a class (i.e. static) property? Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And by the way, what you call "separate class" (named `Code_Behind`) is commonly called a *view model* in the MVVM architectural pattern.

Comment: Yeah I've read that once, but it doesn't really answer much to questions that might rise up. It tells on how it works and what it does, but not "why". Edit: I'll just add that most of this code is just practice to get a grip on data binding and such. I did go through basics of C# programming, but there are still things I need to explore myself

Comment: Not sure which "it" you are talking about here exactly. Anyway, a WPF data binding is notified about a value change of its source property by firing the PropertyChanged event. If the event isnt fired, the binding isn't notified, hence the UI doesn't update.

Comment: Well yes, I do understand that now. It's just that the way properties work is somewhat confusing to me. I mean, if you can set value of a property, almost, like that of a variable, why would you need to use things like **private int _value;**? I previously thought it was the value that was meant to change in order for property's value to change, as stupid as it may sound

Comment: That is the *backing field* of the property, which actually holds the value. How would you be able to implement a property with getter and setter methods without a field that holds the value (not talking about auto properties here).